# I would like to use selenium to select a frame using python

Tags: python, selenium

I can successfully login to web pages but I need to click/select the frame. here is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("URL")
Login = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
Login.send_keys("USER NAME")
Passwd = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
Passwd.send_keys("PSWD")
driver.find_element_by_name('login_submit').click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Test')
```

Here is the frames source code.

```
<div id="Test_topic" ><a href="<link>">Test Spec</a>
```

Comment: So, are you getting any errors doing that ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors but there is no action performed when I use driver.find_element_by_link_text('Test').click() statement.

Comment: did you try it using execute_script ?

Comment: check below answer for performing click using execute_script method.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "here is the frames source code"?  is that div wrapped inside of an iframe element?  If that's the case, you need to switchTo() that frame before looking for that element.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing click() operation via jQuery or JavaScript using execute_script method of selenium. Below is the sample code that will perform the click operation.

```
driver.execute_script('elem = document.getElementById("Test_topic"); a = elem.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]; a.click()')
```

> **execute_script(script, *args)**
>
> Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.
>
> **Args:**  script: The JavaScript to execute.
>   *args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript.
>
> **Usage:**     driver.execute_script(‘document.title’)

Comment: I get this exceptiong.File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.53.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: $ is not defined

Comment: Ohh that means the site you are crawling does not contain JQuery. If you know JavaScript. try it with using javascript inside that function

Comment: I'm looking to automate using python and selenium module. And I'm not familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: @Manoj this is a builtin method of selenium. And you can use that in Python. Did you not read its documentation ?

Comment: @Manoj I've updated my answer. Try and see what you get this time

Answer (score 0):

The link text is not "Test" but "Test Spec".  Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Test Spec')
```

Also, since there is one, it would be better if you find the element by it's id:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_id('Test_topic').find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
```

I personally prefer to use css:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_css_selector('div#Test_topic a').click()
```